# Path variable broken Windows 7?

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables

I have been trying to compile and execute both Python 2.7 and Java programs on my Windows 7 computer. Both of these have been installed, and I am attempting to run my programs off of the command line. Also, they are both included in both the System Path variable, and the User PATH variable. However, when I try to run my programs, I get the error "'python' (or 'java') is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Is there something wrong with my path variable? Is it just broken? Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have you restarted your shell (command prompt) since you updated your PATH?

Comment: @NaveedS: I don't know how many times I'm going to have to leave you comments about this, and perhaps one day you'll reply to one of them. But *code blocks are for **code***, not every proper noun that you find.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I used it to emphasize the System Path variable and User PATH variable

Comment: @Hunter Yes, I have restarted the shell. Still not working.

Comment: @Sam Try reference the executable directly and see if it works. i.e. `C:\Users\Sam\Python27\bin\python my_script.py`

Comment: Your script may be on the path, but python.exe isn't. That is what the error message is telling you if you read it carefully. This isn't really a programming question.

Comment: @NaveedS: Yes, I know. Please do not do that. Code blocks are for code, _not_ for emphasis.

Comment: @Hunter Thanks, I didn't realize that works. But when I just type 'python', it doesn't start the Interpreter, just returns an error. It is supposed to be able to run from any directory, right?

Comment: Depends on how/whether it's "installed".

Comment: I downloaded the Installer from the official Python website, installed it, and saved it in C:\Python27, just for my user.